# Showing that a quotient group $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

I have permutations $\sigma=(135)(27)$, and $\tau = (27)(468)$. $G =\langle \sigma,\tau \rangle$ and $N$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $\tau$, so $N = \langle \tau \rangle$. $|\sigma| = |\tau| = 6$. I have to show that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, but I don't know how to do this in an 'easy' practical way (not theoretical approach).

Normally I start by looking at the quotient groups order, and go by that but I don't see any obvious approach to determine $G$'s order. To start off with, how do I find $G$'s order in a quick way?

Comment: The given subcroup is not normal, and the group has no quotients of order 3.

Comment: First of all, you should check that $N$ is a normal subgroup, otherwise the quotient does not make sense. Obviously, if $N$ is turns out to be normal, then obviously $G/N$ has order $8!/6 \neq 3$, so that $G/N$ is NOT isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_3$. But in the case that $< \tau >$ is not normal, maybe you want to define $N$ as the normal closure of $< \tau >$?

Comment: Turns out it doesnt make sense because i misunderstood a part of the exercise for 40 minutes. Sorry! I've corrected it now. My question about the approach still remains.

Comment: what is the relation between $\sigma$ and $\tau$

Comment: So $G$ is *not* given to be $S_8$ anymore?

Comment: the given items do not satisfy the specified relationship

Comment: @clueless Your question is not clear. Please type the question exactly as it is in the book, and then add what you tried (there's already a vote to close the question as unclear).

Comment: I tried to clarify now. Does it make sense? And yes to your earlier question. @M.Vinay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $G = \langle (135),(27),(468)\rangle$ and $N = \langle (27),(468)\rangle$.

Comment: Too spartan that hint. Could you add a little more? This could complete the other answer.

Comment: This is probably stupid but when using that as a starting point, i get the same order for G and N, so lcm(2,3) = 6. And this can not be as |G|/|N| should be 3.

Comment: I count $3\cdot 2\cdot 3$ elements in $G$ and $2\cdot 3$ elements in $N$.

Comment: Nice, very neat! I've never seen that method before. So you multiply the length of the cycles to get the order instead of lcm?

Comment: I'm identifying $G$ and $N$ with products of groups. For example, there's an isomorphism $N\to \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/3$ taking $(27)$ to $(1,0)$ and $(468)$ to $(0,1)$. The count $2\cdot 3$ is simply $|\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/3|$. This only works because the cycles are disjoint. The group $\langle (27),(467)\rangle$, for example, is nonabelian and hence not a product of abelian groups like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your group is abelian becaus $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commute, the 2-Sylow is the same to the 2-sylow of $\langle\sigma \rangle$ and $\langle\tau\rangle
$ because $\sigma^3=\tau^3$, also your groupe have 3-sylow isomorphic to $Z_3\times Z_3$ and then $G/\langle\tau\rangle$ is $G/\langle\sigma\rangle$ isom $Z_3$

Comment: Very nice...+1 . Yet this begs the question: why the Sylow $\;2\,-$ subgroups are the same in the three cases? And how from here it follows that a Sylow $\;3\,-$ subgroup is isomorphic with $\;C_3\times C_3\;$ ?

Comment: because the groupe G is abelian

Comment: This seems like a neat way to do this using the property that $\sigma^3 = \tau^3$. However we did not learn Sylow theorems this semester, so I'm not really following. Is there a lower level approach?

Comment: 3-sylow is not Z_9 , exposant of G must be 6

Comment: in the cas G abelian and  have order 18, by strcture theorem there are two possibility for G that is $ Z_{18}$  or $Z_6\times Z_3$ the las is your cas.

Comment: Remember that there is no element of order 18 in $S_8$

Comment: @ayadimohammed Your argument seems to be lacking to me. To begin with, it isn't even clear what's the group's order: $\;6,12,18,36,...$? Even if you already show the group is of order $\;18\;$, there are two possibilites for Sylow $\;3\,-$ subgroups, and if it is the cyclic group of order $\;9\;$ then we do not have $\;C_3\times C_3\;$ ...

Comment: @ayadimohammed Not even of order $\;9\;$ ...

Comment: I think that's a good question to show that if $ G = \langle x,y\mid
xy=yx, o(x)=o(y)=2p, x^p=y^p \rangle$ then G  is isomorphic to $
Z_{2p}\times Z_p$

Comment: I answered my question:

the map $\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle \rightarrow G$ that
assigned  $(x^i,y^j)$ to the product $x^iy^j $ is an epimorphisms
but not an monomorphism, we can conclude that   G is as required
thank  you  for your comment